# How do I use "hints" in sympy to prevent a species of subexpression from being evaluated by doit()?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

[The sympy documentation says:](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.doit)

> sympy.core.basic.Basic.doit(**hints)
>
> Evaluate objects that are not evaluated by default like limits, integrals, sums and products. All objects of this kind will be evaluated recursively, **unless some species were excluded via ‘hints’** or unless the ‘deep’ hint was set to ‘False’.

Yet I am unable to find any explanation on how to do this.

I have tried looking at the source code and following what the `.doit()` method does with the `**hints` argument but for every class I've checked it has explicit code for class specific hints and everything else get's kicked up the chain when it calls `.doit(**hints)` on its sub-elements. Short of checking the `.doit()` method for *every single* class in the module I can't think how to figure out how to do what the docs claim is possible.

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

Here's a quick example of something I want to do where this would be useful. If I run the below code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator

A,B = symbols('A B', commutative=False)
x = symbols('x')

expr = 1 + Integral(Commutator(A,B),(x,0,2))

expr.doit()
```

I get the output

```
>>> 1 + 2(AB-BA)
```

This is correct, however I want to keep the commutator intact and get

```
>>> 1 + 2[A,B]
```

---

What I've tried for the above:

If I set `deep=False` then I just get the unevaluated expression, presumably because the outermost layer of the expression is the addition which is already evaluated, so to speak. In this case I certainly could just iterate through the expression and tell it to evaluate the integral with `deep=False` and get what I want but for more complex expressions where I want to keep the commutators intact while evaluating everything else it makes more sense to just be able to tell sympy to leave commutators alone.

Creating the commutator as `UnevaluatedExpr(Commutator(A,B))` doesn't help either since running `.doit()` apparently just blasts through that protective layer.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "masking" is useful here: mask (cover) the expression that you want to remain undone, do the evaluation, restore the masked values. This uses a useful feature of the dictionary method `setdefault` to keep track of the unique replacements to mask entities found with `replace`:

[image]